# PHP exec command is not working in script

Tags: php, cmd

I am running php script to run an exec command. It works fine for all commands other than php. My script is as

```
var_dump(exec("date"));
```

This displays date on page. But when I run any php command it doesn't work.

```
var_dump(exec("php -v"));
var_dump(exec("/usr/bin/php -v"));
```

I tried with shell_exec as well but no result. Just error there 
Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute
If I use incorrect path

```
var_dump(exec("/usr/bin222/php -v"));
```

It return NULL. Its mean my path is correct. I have set permission to file 755. 
Is there need to make changes somewhere else as well.
Thanks

Comment: Not only permission, you need to check the privilage of your apache user to run the exec comman

Comment: if you run server you self, configure it to use shell, if  its hosted, than not much you can do

Comment: What has your question to do with `cmd`? `cmd` is the Windows command interpreter/shell, as can be clearly seen in the description for the tag you've used. If you're using `php.exe` on Windows, and using it with its `-v` option in turn opens `cmd.exe`, then you're probably okay, although it would be preferred to execute the shell, _(in this case `cmd.exe`)_ with the absolute path to `php.exe` and the option `-v`, as its arguments.